# How to restart background service in .net core 2.2

Tags: .net-core, background-service, .net-core-2.2

I am creating a BackgroundService in my project, using the .net core 2.2 BackgroundService class,
I have a problem trying to restart the service,
I have noticed that when I call the "StartAsync" function (after running the "StopAsync" function) The "ExcecuteAsync" function is called (by the StartAsync base function) with a cancelled Token.
After looking at the BackgroundService class I've noticed that the
BackgroundService contains an inner CancellationTokenSource that I cannot reset anywhere. [BackgroundService source](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs).

Is there a way to reset or replace the cancellationToken inside the BackgroundService?

Sample Code:

```
namespace Services.Background
{
    [DisplayName("Device Structure Service")]
    public class DeviceStructureService : BackgroundService
    {

        private readonly ILogger<DeviceStructureService> _logger;

        public DeviceStructureService(ILogger<DeviceStructureService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;            
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            stoppingToken.Register(() =>  _logger?.LogDebug($"{serviceName} background task is stopping."));

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {                

                _logger?.LogInformation($"The {serviceName} running at: {DateTimeOffset.Now}");
                try
                {
                    await DoWork();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    _logger?.LogCritical(exception.ToString());
                }
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);

            }

            await StopAsync(stoppingToken);


        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger?.LogInformation($"The {serviceName} stopped at: {DateTime.Now}");

            return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger?.LogInformation($"The {serviceName} started at: {DateTime.Now}");

            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Since the `BackgroundService` source code is available, there is nothing stopping the creation of a local version that has the desired functionality

Comment: I'm trying to avoid creating a local version of BackgroundService in my code

Comment: Well then there is nothing else that can be done with the target token source as it is private and readonly in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to reset or replace the cancellationToken inside the BackgroundService?

No

as the target token source is `private` and `readonly` in the base class.

*BackgroundService*

```
private readonly CancellationTokenSource _stoppingCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Since the `BackgroundService` source code is available, there is nothing stopping the creation of a local version that has the desired functionality